# Filter array of objects where object property is date

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, momentjs

I have an array of objects where each object looks like this

```
{
   "ActionDateTime": "2018-07-31T11:07:11Z",
   "ExternalID": 3962770,
   "GrandTotal": 707.5,
   "InternalID": 52858173,
   "ItemName": "Ricciolini Pasta",
}
```

I need to filter this array (maybe using moment.js) in such a way that "ActionDateType" will be equal to current Month (moment().format('MMMM') //August)

This is my code:

```js
var array = [];
      
array = data.filter(function (el) {
   var a = el.ActionDateTime
   return moment(a).format('MMMM') == moment().format('MMMM')
})
        
console.log(array)
```

Comment: everything is possible. Tried to do this?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich is right! you should at least try... Hint: It will certainly require a time range.

Comment: @Salketer Yeah, I tried to do this, but it returns an empty array

Comment: if u tried, show your code

Comment: You are only showing us one record... So just in case, the record you shown is from July, while we are in August now, that might be why you get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScripts `Date` to do that.

Since your `ActionDateTime` value is in a parsable format, you can use `Date.parse`, to get a timestamp.

`let date = Date.parse ("2018-07-31T11:07:11Z")`

To get the current month, you can use `new Date().getMonth ()`.

Combining those too, you get something like this.

```js
let arr = [{
   "ActionDateTime": "2018-08-31T11:07:11Z", //<-- Note that i changed 07 to 08
   "ExternalID": 3962770,
   "GrandTotal": 707.5,
   "InternalID": 52858173,
   "ItemName": "Ricciolini Pasta",
}]


let tempDate   = new Date (); //Initialise a new Date
let currentMonth = tempDate.getMonth (); //Get the current month, from the untouched date.

let filtered = arr.filter (({ActionDateTime}) => 
tempDate.setTime (Date.parse (ActionDateTime)) && 
tempDate.getMonth () === currentMonth);
   
console.log (filtered)
```

As pointed out in the comments: i changed the Date such that the filter returns an entry when run in August.

Comment: Yes, we're in August, the month you're comparing the current date to is July

Comment: Try changing ActionDateTime to `"2018-08-31T11:07:11Z"`

Comment: Since it is the accepted answer, you might want to edit just so the code doesn't return an empty array... That is the main problem OP was having.

Comment: @Salketer Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer, however, this will only work for the next month.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function timeTest() {
  let dateStr = '2018-07-31T11:07:11Z'
  let dateTs = new Date(dateStr)
  let ret = dateTs.getFullYear().toString() + '.' +
            (dateTs.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '.' +
            dateTs.getDate().toString()

  console.log(ret)
}

timeTest()
```

I think you can use javascript's api.

Comment: I think it not that way, because i need to filter array with a hundred objects by current month

Answer (score 0):

I have modified OP's code (which was certainly working, but I needed to remove the moment dependency for it to work here).

What you were doing was right, but you need to filter data from current month while your data is from last month. I've added 3 data, 1 of last month, 2 of current month but one from last year. Commented out the return statement that accounts for the year too, not sure if it is wanted but I expect it was just forgotten.

```js
var data = [
{
   "ActionDateTime": "2018-07-31T11:07:11Z",
   "ExternalID": 3962770,
   "GrandTotal": 707.5,
   "InternalID": 52858173,
   "ItemName": "Ricciolini Pasta",
},
{
   "ActionDateTime": "2018-08-02T11:07:11Z",
   "ExternalID": 3962770,
   "GrandTotal": 707.5,
   "InternalID": 52858173,
   "ItemName": "Ricciolini Pasta",
},
{
   "ActionDateTime": "2017-08-02T11:07:11Z",
   "ExternalID": 3962770,
   "GrandTotal": 707.5,
   "InternalID": 52858173,
   "ItemName": "Ricciolini Pasta",
}];

let array = [];
let curDate = new Date();
array = data.filter(function (el) {
   let a = new Date(el.ActionDateTime)
   //return a.getMonth() ==curDate.getMonth() && a.getYear() ==curDate.getYear()
   return a.getMonth() ==curDate.getMonth()
})
        
console.log(array)
```